# npm rebuild error after node update

Tags: ubuntu, npm

since my last update of node in v12, i can't use npm rebuild option.

I tried to purge and reinstall node but it failed, i finally deleted node_modules manually (if you want to see what i deleted, you can check the commented lines on the uploaded .txt on this link : https://filebin.net/twbmbrrd23z4s0z4 )

I reinstalled a node v10.12.0 (like previously) with a npm v6.4.1 but even after this, i still have the following error :

```
root@xxxx-VirtualBox:/home/xxxx/Desktop/opencti# npm rebuild

> core-js@3.1.4 postinstall /home/xxxx/Desktop/opencti/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/xxxx/Desktop/opencti/node_modules/core-js/scripts/postinstall'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
ignore

> protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall /home/xxxx/Desktop/opencti/node_modules/apollo-engine-reporting-protobuf/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/xxxx/Desktop/opencti/node_modules/apollo-engine-reporting-protobuf/node_modules/protobufjs/scripts/postinstall'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-15T06_03_57_920Z-debug.log
```

If you have any idea of what else i could do, i liked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, i just had to clean cache of npm and use nmp install command in my working's directory; now it's working.